# Conditional includes in Single Table Inheritance models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have my models like this:

```
A < ActiveRecord::Base
- has_many :z

B < A
- has_many :y

C < A
- has_many :x
```

Somewhere, I want to do something like:

```
A.all.includes([:z,:y, :x])
```

But it doesn't work, because some items are from specific type `B` and other are `C`.

How can I conditionally include one or another?

Comment: I'm not sure that would work, and i don't have any rails app at hand to test it, but you could try `A.includes( :z ).merge( B.includes :y ).merge( C.includes :x )`

Comment: It doesn't work. Thanks anyway.

Comment: More specific: The second merge will made the query return only the `C` types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I don't find a real fix, I'm doins this:

```
all = B.includes([:z, :y])
all = (all + C.includes([:z, :x])).sort_by(&:date)
```

It isn't that pretty, but solves the issue for the moment.
Lots of speed improvement.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A bit messy, but fully correct solution.

```
A.from("(#{B.includes(:y).to_sql} UNION #{C.includes(:x).to_sql}) as #{A.table_name}").includes(:z)
```